# preventing from the site any external links

Tags: apache, .htaccess, dokuwiki

I am using DokuWiki and as we've tried to secure it as much as possible the best security for us to keep it's location on our server secret. Therefore we want to make sure no link can be clicked on any pages which would reveal the location of our infrastructure. Is there any way to configure this restriction with DokuWiki or are there known ways to pass URLs through a third party?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you tried to protect the site with .htaccess and .htpasswd?? Is a good solution for other to not enter on your site.

And if the site is online you should include a robots.txt to avoid crawlers to index it

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /
```

Hope i help you